# Injecting Laravel 5.7 dompdf with angularjs, how to call the print route from laravel in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, laravel-5.7

I have shown data on a view from laravel and when I go to that route from laravel route then I can print the data but when I try to open that route from angularjs using ui-router or simply calling my laravel route inside angularjs then I am not redirecting to that print page.

How to go to laravel route from angularjs to print that data?

I am using dompdf.

Here is my route

```
Route::get('quotationInvoice','QuotationController@getQuoteInvoice');
```

Here is my laravel controller

```
public function getQuoteInvoice()
{
  $id = $this->getQuoteID();
  $data1 = quotationGridModel::find($id)->customer()->get();
  $data2 = quotationGridModel::where('QUOTE_ID',$id)->get();
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('printinvoice',['data1'=>$data1,'data2'=>$data2]);
  return $pdf->stream('invoice.pdf');
 }
```

When I write `quotationInvoice` in browser it gives me the print data, but how can I use this route in angularjs to get the job done? I have applied many methods like angularjs ui.router, `window.assign(url);` etc. but really don't understand. And in my full project I have used angularjs ui.router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer I hope it will help others too,

This is angularjs code

```
$http.get("quotationInvoice")
.then(function(response)){
 var res = response;
 console.log(res.config.url);
  location.assign(res.config.url);
  });
```

I have accessed the url from console response, and now it works Great!